# Linearly independent sets and span (polynomials)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, solution-verification

We have the set $S = \{1,x-1,(x-1)^2,\dots,(x-1)^n\}$. They ask to proof whether or not it is linearly independent and find a basis of $span(S)$. I have proved it is linearly independent by the following method (which I don't quite know if it is correct):

We consider the linear combination

$a_0 + a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-1)^2 + \dots + a_n(x-1)^n = 0$

which has to be satisfied for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, differentiating both sides $n$ times, we have:

$a_1x + 2a_2(x-1) + \dots +na_n(x-1)^{n-1}=0 $

$\vdots$

$a_{n-1}x(n-1)! + a_n(x-1)n!=0$

$a_nx\cdot n!=0$

So, from the last equation, we obtain $a_n=0$, which implies that $a_{n-1}=0$ and so on until we get to $a_0 =0$. Therefore, we obtain that $S$ is linearly independent. Am I right? If so, what would be a basis for the $span(S)$, wouldn't it be $S$ itself?

I would really appreciate any kind of help. Besides, if anyone notices any flaw in my proof it will be welcomed!

Thank you!

Comment: Everything you said is good.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might help. Consider the polynomial

$$p(x)=a_0 + a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-1)^2 + \dots + a_n(x-1)^n = 0$$

This means that $p(t)=0$, where $t=x-1$ for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Note that a non-constant polynomial has at most a finite number of roots. One of these roots is zero; dividing by this root and invoking the same argument, we therefore have that $p(t)$ is a constant polynomial. In particular, it is the zero polynomial.